# Create select dropwdown picker to filter values in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dropdown

I want user to select their symptoms from a list. It is gonna be a very long list so I would like to filter it but at the same time have proper dropdown select item. Something like this:

[image: Dropdown select with filter input xamarin]

There is Xamarin.Forms Picker (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/) but it can only display itewms in a list to select, right? No possibility to input.

How can I achieve something similar like picture in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: use a ListView with a searchbox, or there are several third party controls that provide a more typical dropdown control

Comment: Try https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the searchbar or the Xamarin.Forms Shell search to realize the element you want.

```
<SearchBar Placeholder="Search items..."
           CancelButtonColor="Orange"
           PlaceholderColor="Orange"
           TextColor="Orange"
           TextTransform="Lowercase"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="Medium"
           FontAttributes="Italic" />
```

More information you can refer to [Xamarin.Forms SearchBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar).